# Present Continuous & "all the time"

Tags: present-continuous

As I understand, sometimes we can use the Present Continuous with key adverb "always". Is it possible to do it if I put "all the time" instead "always"?

1. Why are you always criticising me?

vs

2. Why are you criticising me all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both correct: *always* and *all the time* are synonymous, but as you said, *always* is an adverb (which usually goes before the verb it modifies), and *all the time* is an [adverbial phrase](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/adverb-phrase-examples.html) (which describes the phrase immediately before it, but is not itself an adverb, and must follow the phrase it modifies).